# Ember/Handlebars: Custom helper rendering

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Within my custom helper, how do I render a button which itself uses a helper (in this case the "action" helper)?  I'm trying this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('actionButtons', function(context, options) {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString("<button {{action 'remove'}} class='destroy'>Delete</button>");
}
```

But I'm just getting a non-working button with malformed html.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a partial instead of a helper on this.

```
{{partial 'buttons'}}
```

Or you can do

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('actionButtons', Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'buttons'
}));

{{actionButtons}}
```

And the template would have something like

```
<button {{action 'remove'}} class='destroy'>Delete</button>
```

Or you can do

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('actionButtons', Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<button {{action 'remove'}} class='destroy'>Delete</button>')
}));

{{actionButtons}}
```

Comment: What if the render is contingent on some statement evaluating to true, e.g. `if (context.content.get('userID') == App.currentUser.get('id')) {
  return Handlebars.compile("<button {{action 'remove'}} class='destroy'>Delete</button>");
 }`